# React Native Expo Error 500 Related to expo/hashAssetFiles.js. Bundler stuck in building JS Bundle

Tags: react-native, expo, http-status-code-500

I Encountered sudden error in my expo(react native) project. i've tried the debug mode to get more info about the problem. in my metro bundler console, it shows error as below and get stuck in building js bundle.

```
::ffff:192.168.0.102 - - [07/Mar/2019:10:59:36 +0000] "GET /node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&minify=true&hot=false&assetPlugin=D%3A%5CReact%5CBillBord%5Cnode_modules%5Cexpo%5Ctools%5ChashAssetFiles.js HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"
```

i have attached the screenshot of metro bundler here.[image: Metro Bundler Debug Console]

Comment: restarting did not work? I also encounter sudden errors with expo project even if I haven't changed anything significant.

Comment: i've tried all the things including expo clean installation with node. still it has error related to hashAssetFiles.js

Comment: How about using git to revert to a previous codebase? Or starting a new expo project and importing the app codes.

Comment: yup, i also tried it, after hard reset my local repo.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry but I have no idea. Have you tried out this forum? (https://forums.expo.io/) On expo related issues, It is more active than stack overflow